# Is there any way to keep my Extended Floating action Button Fixed Position When using scrolling behavior

Tags: android, android-support-library, floating-action-button, android-coordinatorlayout, vertical-scrolling

This is my main activity.xml file which is the navigation page. Every Navigation menu item when selected is inflated on a different Co-ordinator Layout file.
I use Co-ordinator Layout because I want to hide the app bar when scrolling the list. My Activity Layout is working exactly as I wanted but the fragment layout is the problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".Home">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@color/purple_700"
                android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Light"


                />
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>


        <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"

            android:background="@color/white"
            app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior">


        </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/home_nav"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/nav_menu" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

and this is my fragment layout XML...I use a recycler view to populate a list of objects. The Problem is when I scroll the list the Extended FAB is also moving up when I scroll up and moving down when I scroll down. I Want this E FAB to stay fixed when I scroll the list.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"

    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/assembly_recycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.ExtendedFloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/new_assembly"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="81dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/new_assembly"

        android:text="@string/new_assembly"
        app:icon="@drawable/ic_add"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/assembly_recycler"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end" />


</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

whenever I scroll my recycler view the Extended Floating Action Button is also scrolling.

Is there any way I could keep my Extended FAB fixed like in Gmail App on every fragment.

Comment: Is your fab action fragment related? I mean Fragment A has this EFab others will not have this?  Why do you use coordinator layout as the fragment container. why not frame layout?

Answer (score 0):

> I use `CoordinatorLayout` because I want to hide the app bar when
> scrolling the list. My Activity Layout is working exactly as I wanted
> but the fragment layout is the problem.

The `CoordinatorLayout` which is defined in the main layout seems to be working but the another `CoordinatorLayout` which you've set for your container seems to be unnecessary. Try replacing it with a FrameLayout as your content container.

> Is there any way I could keep my Extended FAB fixed like in Gmail App
> on every fragment.

You'll need to set your `Extended FAB` in the Activity layout and using `FrameLayout` instead of the `CoordinatorLayout` as your container: (This is the proper approach)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Light" />
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/white"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.ExtendedFloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/new_assembly"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end" />

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/home_nav"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_view_header"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And for your `Fragment` layout, you can use `ConstraintLayout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/assembly_recycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```